# How to find something in a 2D array when only looking for one item of the 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

for example if I had

```
array=[["A",1],["B",2],["C",1]]
```

is there any way I can find ["A",1] by just looking for "A"? I'm trying to use this in a situation where the first thing in the array is unique so there's no point in looking at the second, also I have no way of knowing what the second variable is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over items present inside the outer list and check that the first element of inner list satisfies a particular condition.

```
>>> a=[["A",1],["B",2],["C",1]]
>>> next(i for i in a if i[0] == 'A')
['A', 1]
>>> [i for i in a if i[0] == 'A']
[['A', 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in control of the datatype, depending on whate else you're doing with this object, a dictionary may be a better choice for this:

Rather than

```
array=[["A",1],["B",2],["C",1]]
```

use

```
d={"A":1, "B":2, "C":1}
```

Then you can access the element associated with `"A"` simply with

```
>> d["A"]

1
```

If you want to transform your list into a dictionary:

```
d = dict(array)
```